# How to store user's first-name and last-names in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I can not see a first-name or full name field in Drupal's create/edit user form. I am using Drupal 6. How do I store a user's full name in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to enable the Profile module for that. This module lets you add fields to users.

See [information about the module in the handbook](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/profile), and [some nice instructions here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/managing-users-profiles-drupal6-social-networking) (under "Adding special properties to user profiles").

Answer (score 2):

Drupal supports fully configurable profiles. Turn on the module (it's in core) and navigate to `/admin/user/profile` to add/edit fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use Drupal's built-in [profile module](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/profile).

Answer (score 1):

I realize that everyone's suggesting the profile module, and I agree that that will work fine on small enough sites, if you don't have too many user profile fields and not too many users... but it can be a hog on larger sites.

I'd also point out the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module, which allows you to create a node type and use it to extend the user's information that way, which also has the advantage of giving you the width and breadth of CCK for creating fields, instead of being stuck with profile's limited selection.